# Baseboard was not removed when new drywall installed. How to fix

Tags: patching-drywall

The drywall in my living room only goes up to the baseboard and is extremely uneven. It is cracking at the point of the baseboards. Can I remove the baseboards and patch in new drywall some how? Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative that may work for you, depending on the type and height of the existing baseboard, is to replace it with a taller one. Probably need a couple inches above the existing height to make it cover the bottom of the drywall, especially where it has started cracking. If your existing baseboard is 2" - 3" tall then remove it and install ~ 4" - 5" to replace it. If your existing baseboard is already > 4" tall then this may not work so well. Cutting and painting baseboards is a lot of work - but a lot less than patching and painting all that drywall.

If you are going to stain the new baseboards, definitely do that before installation. If you are going to paint them (typically either a gloss or semi-gloss variety of the same color as on the walls or sometimes either plain white or a contrasting color - totally subjective), you can paint them before installation (measure, cut, paint, install) and then touch-up after installation, or you can paint after installation.

Comment: Definitely a good idea.  Might I suggest painting or finishing the baseboard before installing it?

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself a [superbar](https://www.vaughanmfg.com/Products/B215-Superbar-15__45001.aspx) and just pry the baseboard off. You might have to replace any shoe it had (it doesn't pry nicely) but baseboards tend to be shot on with 16 or 18 gauge airgun nails. Once it's pulled off, use pliers to pull the nails through the back. Now replace your drywall.

You'll want a nailgun with 1.5 - 2.5" nails to put it back up. Either that, or be prepared to do a lot of driving of finish nails by hand. Once it's back up, putty up the holes and paint it. Should look just fine on the new drywall. Just be sure to paint the drywall first and then put the baseboards up.